# Why do i get ExceptionInInitializerError in my code?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, jetty, httpclient, cometd

I would like to know why am i getting an ExceptionInInitializerError?

Platform:

- Windows;
- Glassfish 3.1.2.2;
- Notepade++;
- Cometd java libraries;
- Jetty libraries;
- Javac command line;

I'm walking my way to set up a cometd web application. After some debugging i realized that jetty: HttpClient class is causing ExceptionInInitializerError, can someone tell me why is that?

What i did is that i went commenting code lines till i found where the problem occurs.

here is my CometD_Client class where the error occurs:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.net.URL;
import org.cometd.bayeux.*;
import org.cometd.bayeux.client.*;
import org.cometd.server.*;
import org.cometd.client.*;
import org.cometd.common.*;
import org.cometd.client.transport.*;
import org.eclipse.jetty.client.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class CometD_Client
{
    private String CurrentDate;

    private String BayeuxServerURL$;

    private HttpClient JettyHttpClient;

    private Map<String, Object> TransportOptions;

    private ClientTransport C_Transport;

    private BayeuxClient C_Session;

    private boolean HandIsShaken£ = false;

    DayTimePanel Panel;


    public CometD_Client(String BayeuxServerURL$, DayTimePanel Panel)
    {
        this.BayeuxServerURL$ = BayeuxServerURL$;
        this.Panel = Panel;

        // Create (and eventually set up) Jetty's HttpClient;
        JettyHttpClient = new HttpClient();

        /*
        try
        {
            JettyHttpClient.start();
        }
        catch(Exception E) {}
        /*
        */

        // Prepare the transport;
        //TransportOptions = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        //ClientTransport C_Transport = 
        //  LongPollingTransport.create(TransportOptions, 
        //                              JettyHttpClient  );

        //C_Session = new BayeuxClient(BayeuxServerURL$, C_Transport);

        //C_Session.handshake();

        //HandIsShaken£ = 
        //  C_Session.waitFor(1000, BayeuxClient.State.CONNECTED);

        if(HandIsShaken£)
        {
            // TO DO: Output that the handshake had succeed;
        }
        else
        {
            // TO DO: Output that the handshake had failed;
        }


        /*
        C_Session.getChannel(Channel.META_HANDSHAKE).addListener
        (
         new ClientSessionChannel.MessageListener()
         {
            @Override
            public void onMessage(ClientSessionChannel ThisMetaChanel,
                                  Message msg)
            {
                // TO DO: Output msg to check it out;

                C_Session.getChannel("/my/channel").subscribe
                (
                 new ClientSessionChannel.MessageListener()
                 {
                    @Override
                    public void onMessage(ClientSessionChannel ThisChanel,
                                          Message msg)
                    {
                        CurrentDate = msg.getJSON();

                        OutputCurrentDate();
                    }
                 }
                );
            }
         }
        );
        /*
        */
    }

    public boolean GetIfHandIsShaken£()
    {
        return HandIsShaken£;
    }

    public String GetCurrentDate()
    {
        return CurrentDate;
    }

    /*
    private void OutputCurrentDate()
    {
        Panel.GetJTF().setText(CurrentDate);
    }
    /*
    */
}
```

EDIT:
Applying `asadmin generate-jvm-report --type=thread` this is the log i get:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<hotspot_log version='160 1' process='4732' time_ms='1364843903652'>
<vm_version>
<name>
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
</name>
<release>
23.1-b03
</release>
<info>
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.1-b03) for windows-x86 JRE (1.7.0_05-b06), built on Jun 27 2012 00:51:27 by &quot;java_re&quot; with unknown MS VC++:1600
</info>
</vm_version>
<vm_arguments>
<args>
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9009 -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=192m -XX:NewRatio=2 -XX:+LogVMOutput -XX:LogFile=C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1/logs/jvm.log -Xmx512m -javaagent:C:/glassfish3/glassfish/lib/monitor/flashlight-agent.jar -Dosgi.shell.telnet.maxconn=1 -Dfelix.fileinstall.disableConfigSave=false -Djdbc.drivers=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver -Dfelix.fileinstall.dir=C:\glassfish3\glassfish/modules/autostart/ -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks -Dosgi.shell.telnet.port=6666 -Djava.security.policy=C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/server.policy -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfelix.fileinstall.log.level=2 -Dfelix.fileinstall.poll=5000 -Dcom.sun.aas.instanceRoot=C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1 -Dosgi.shell.telnet.ip=127.0.0.1 -Dcom.sun.enterprise.config.config_environment_factory_class=com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.AppserverConfigEnvironmentFactory -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\glassfish3\glassfish/modules/endorsed;C:\glassfish3\glassfish/lib/endorsed -Dcom.sun.aas.installRoot=C:\glassfish3\glassfish -Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.startTransient=true -Djava.ext.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05/lib/ext;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/ext;C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1/lib/ext -Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start=true -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/cacerts.jks -Dcom.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias=s1as -Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/login.conf -DANTLR_USE_DIRECT_CLASS_LOADING=true -Dgosh.args=--nointeractive -Djava.library.path=C:/glassfish3/glassfish/lib;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin;C:/WINDOWS/Sun/Java/bin;C:/WINDOWS/system32;C:/WINDOWS;C:/WINDOWS/system32/wbem;C:/Sun/AppServer/bin;C:/glassfish3/bin;C:/glassfish3;C:/glassfish3/ant/bin;C:/glassfish3/glassfish/bin;C:/Sun/AppServer/jdk/bin;C:/Program Files/Ant/bin;C:/Sun/AppServer/lib;C:/Program Files/Flex_SDK/bin;C:/CometD/samples/client_server_API/web 
</args>
<command>
com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain -domainname domain1 -asadmin-args --host,,,localhost,,,--port,,,4848,,,--secure=false,,,--terse=false,,,--echo=false,,,--interactive=true,,,start-domain,,,--verbose=false,,,--debug=false,,,--domaindir,,,C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains,,,domain1 -instancename server -verbose false -debug false -asadmin-classpath C:/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/admin-cli.jar -asadmin-classname com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AsadminMain -upgrade false -type DAS -domaindir C:/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1 -read-stdin true
</command>
<launcher>
SUN_STANDARD
</launcher>
<properties>
java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification
java.vm.version=23.1-b03
java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
java.vm.info=mixed mode, sharing
java.ext.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05/lib/ext;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05/jre/lib/ext;C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1/lib/ext
java.endorsed.dirs=C:\glassfish3\glassfish/modules/endorsed;C:\glassfish3\glassfish/lib/endorsed
sun.boot.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\bin
java.library.path=C:/glassfish3/glassfish/lib;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin;C:/WINDOWS/Sun/Java/bin;C:/WINDOWS/system32;C:/WINDOWS;C:/WINDOWS/system32/wbem;C:/Sun/AppServer/bin;C:/glassfish3/bin;C:/glassfish3;C:/glassfish3/ant/bin;C:/glassfish3/glassfish/bin;C:/Sun/AppServer/jdk/bin;C:/Program Files/Ant/bin;C:/Sun/AppServer/lib;C:/Program Files/Flex_SDK/bin;C:/CometD/samples/client_server_API/web
java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre
java.class.path=C:/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/glassfish.jar
sun.boot.class.path=C:\glassfish3\glassfish/modules/endorsed\javax.annotation.jar;C:\glassfish3\glassfish/modules/endorsed\jaxb-api-osgi.jar;C:\glassfish3\glassfish/modules/endorsed\webservices-api-osgi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\classes
java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vm.specification.version=1.7
java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation
osgi.shell.telnet.maxconn=1
felix.fileinstall.disableConfigSave=false
jdbc.drivers=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
felix.fileinstall.dir=C:\glassfish3\glassfish/modules/autostart/
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks
osgi.shell.telnet.port=6666
java.security.policy=C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/server.policy
java.awt.headless=true
felix.fileinstall.log.level=2
felix.fileinstall.poll=5000
com.sun.aas.instanceRoot=C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1
osgi.shell.telnet.ip=127.0.0.1
com.sun.enterprise.config.config_environment_factory_class=com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.AppserverConfigEnvironmentFactory
com.sun.aas.installRoot=C:\glassfish3\glassfish
felix.fileinstall.bundles.startTransient=true
felix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start=true
javax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/cacerts.jks
com.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias=s1as
java.security.auth.login.config=C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/login.conf
ANTLR_USE_DIRECT_CLASS_LOADING=true
gosh.args=--nointeractive
sun.java.command=com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain -domainname domain1 -asadmin-args --host,,,localhost,,,--port,,,4848,,,--secure=false,,,--terse=false,,,--echo=false,,,--interactive=true,,,start-domain,,,--verbose=false,,,--debug=false,,,--domaindir,,,C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains,,,domain1 -instancename server -verbose false -debug false -asadmin-classpath C:/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/admin-cli.jar -asadmin-classname com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AsadminMain -upgrade false -type DAS -domaindir C:/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1 -read-stdin true
sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD
</properties>
</vm_arguments>
<tty>
<writer thread='2068'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='java/io/BufferedReader' witness='java/io/LineNumberReader' stamp='0.997'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='java/util/jar/JarFile' witness='sun/net/www/protocol/jar/URLJarFile' stamp='1.229'/>
<writer thread='4180'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' ctxk='java/util/Properties' x='java/util/Hashtable put (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='java/security/Provider' stamp='1.733'/>
<writer thread='3972'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='org/apache/felix/framework/wiring/BundleRequirementImpl' witness='org/apache/felix/framework/resolver/HostedRequirement' stamp='16.176'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='java/io/ObjectInputStream' witness='com/sun/hk2/component/AbstractInhabitantImpl$1' stamp='17.178'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='java/io/ObjectInputStream' witness='com/sun/hk2/component/AbstractInhabitantImpl$1' stamp='17.178'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='java/io/ObjectInputStream' witness='com/sun/hk2/component/AbstractInhabitantImpl$1' stamp='17.178'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='java/io/ObjectInputStream' witness='com/sun/hk2/component/AbstractInhabitantImpl$1' stamp='17.178'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='java/io/ObjectInputStream' witness='com/sun/hk2/component/AbstractInhabitantImpl$1' stamp='17.178'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='java/io/ObjectInputStream' witness='com/sun/hk2/component/AbstractInhabitantImpl$1' stamp='17.178'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='java/io/ObjectInputStream' witness='com/sun/hk2/component/AbstractInhabitantImpl$1' stamp='17.178'/>
<writer thread='2068'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='org/jvnet/hk2/component/MultiMap' witness='org/glassfish/api/admin/ParameterMap' stamp='20.496'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='org/jvnet/hk2/component/MultiMap' witness='org/glassfish/api/admin/ParameterMap' stamp='20.496'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='org/jvnet/hk2/component/MultiMap' witness='org/glassfish/api/admin/ParameterMap' stamp='20.496'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='org/jvnet/hk2/component/MultiMap' witness='org/glassfish/api/admin/ParameterMap' stamp='20.496'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='org/jvnet/hk2/component/MultiMap' witness='org/glassfish/api/admin/ParameterMap' stamp='20.496'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='org/jvnet/hk2/component/MultiMap' witness='org/glassfish/api/admin/ParameterMap' stamp='20.496'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='org/jvnet/hk2/component/MultiMap' witness='org/glassfish/api/admin/ParameterMap' stamp='20.496'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='org/jvnet/hk2/component/MultiMap' witness='org/glassfish/api/admin/ParameterMap' stamp='20.496'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='java/util/WeakHashMap' witness='com/sun/jmx/mbeanserver/MBeanIntrospector$PerInterfaceMap' stamp='21.229'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='java/util/WeakHashMap' witness='com/sun/jmx/mbeanserver/MBeanIntrospector$PerInterfaceMap' stamp='21.230'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' ctxk='java/io/IOException' x='java/lang/Throwable getMessage ()Ljava/lang/String;' witness='java/rmi/RemoteException' stamp='21.605'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream' witness='com/sun/common/util/logging/LoggingOutputStream' stamp='22.522'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream' witness='com/sun/common/util/logging/LoggingOutputStream' stamp='22.523'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream' witness='com/sun/common/util/logging/LoggingOutputStream' stamp='22.523'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream' witness='com/sun/common/util/logging/LoggingOutputStream' stamp='22.523'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream' witness='com/sun/common/util/logging/LoggingOutputStream' stamp='22.523'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='java/util/ArrayList' witness='com/sun/enterprise/config/serverbeans/Applications$Duck$1' stamp='25.477'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='java/util/ArrayList' witness='com/sun/enterprise/config/serverbeans/Applications$Duck$1' stamp='25.477'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='java/util/ArrayList' witness='com/sun/enterprise/config/serverbeans/Applications$Duck$1' stamp='25.477'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='java/util/ArrayList' witness='com/sun/enterprise/config/serverbeans/Applications$Duck$1' stamp='25.477'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='java/util/ArrayList' witness='com/sun/enterprise/config/serverbeans/Applications$Duck$1' stamp='25.477'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='java/util/ArrayList' witness='com/sun/enterprise/config/serverbeans/Applications$Duck$1' stamp='25.477'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='java/util/ArrayList' witness='com/sun/enterprise/config/serverbeans/Applications$Duck$1' stamp='25.477'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='java/util/ArrayList' witness='com/sun/enterprise/config/serverbeans/Applications$Duck$1' stamp='25.478'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='java/util/ArrayList' witness='com/sun/enterprise/config/serverbeans/Applications$Duck$1' stamp='25.478'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='java/util/ArrayList' witness='com/sun/enterprise/config/serverbeans/Applications$Duck$1' stamp='25.478'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='java/util/ArrayList' witness='com/sun/enterprise/config/serverbeans/Applications$Duck$1' stamp='25.478'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='java/util/ArrayList$Itr' witness='java/util/ArrayList$ListItr' stamp='26.987'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='java/util/ArrayList$Itr' witness='java/util/ArrayList$ListItr' stamp='26.987'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='java/util/ArrayList$Itr' witness='java/util/ArrayList$ListItr' stamp='26.987'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/lang/SecurityManager checkPropertyAccess (Ljava/lang/String;)V' witness='com/sun/enterprise/security/J2EESecurityManager' stamp='27.822'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/lang/SecurityManager checkPackageAccess (Ljava/lang/String;)V' witness='com/sun/enterprise/security/J2EESecurityManager' stamp='27.822'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/lang/ThreadLocal get ()Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='org/glassfish/web/admin/monitor/HttpServiceStatsProvider$1' stamp='30.803'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/lang/ThreadLocal get ()Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='org/glassfish/web/admin/monitor/HttpServiceStatsProvider$1' stamp='30.803'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/lang/ThreadLocal get ()Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='org/glassfish/web/admin/monitor/HttpServiceStatsProvider$1' stamp='30.803'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/lang/ThreadLocal get ()Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='org/glassfish/web/admin/monitor/HttpServiceStatsProvider$1' stamp='30.803'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/lang/ThreadLocal get ()Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='org/glassfish/web/admin/monitor/HttpServiceStatsProvider$1' stamp='30.803'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/lang/ThreadLocal get ()Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='org/glassfish/web/admin/monitor/HttpServiceStatsProvider$1' stamp='30.803'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/lang/ThreadLocal get ()Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='org/glassfish/web/admin/monitor/HttpServiceStatsProvider$1' stamp='30.803'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/lang/ThreadLocal get ()Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='org/glassfish/web/admin/monitor/HttpServiceStatsProvider$1' stamp='30.803'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/lang/ThreadLocal get ()Ljava/lang/Object;' witness='org/glassfish/web/admin/monitor/HttpServiceStatsProvider$1' stamp='30.803'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='java/util/logging/Level' witness='com/sun/enterprise/util/logging/IASLevel' stamp='30.959'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/util/ArrayList add (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z' witness='javax/management/AttributeList' stamp='33.034'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' x='java/util/ArrayList add (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z' witness='javax/management/AttributeList' stamp='33.035'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' ctxk='org/w3c/dom/Node' x='com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/dom/NodeImpl appendChild (Lorg/w3c/dom/Node;)Lorg/w3c/dom/Node;' witness='org/w3c/dom/Node' stamp='34.497'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/util/NamespaceSupport' witness='com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/impl/xs/SchemaNamespaceSupport' stamp='34.567'/>
<dependency_failed type='unique_concrete_method' ctxk='org/w3c/dom/NamedNodeMap' x='com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/dom/NamedNodeMapImpl getLength ()I' witness='org/w3c/dom/NamedNodeMap' stamp='34.568'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/xni/QName' witness='com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/impl/dv/xs/QNameDV$XQName' stamp='34.836'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/xni/QName' witness='com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/impl/dv/xs/QNameDV$XQName' stamp='34.836'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_type' ctxk='com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/xni/QName' witness='com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/impl/dv/xs/QNameDV$XQName' stamp='34.836'/>
<dependency_failed type='leaf_typ
```

This is my deployment descriptor if it would help, web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>cometd</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.cometd.server.CometdServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>timeout</param-name>
            <param-value>60000</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>logLevel</param-name>
            <param-value>3</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>cometd</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/cometd/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>configuration</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>CometDServletInitializer</servlet-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>

</web-app>
```

Sorry for asking help to debug my code, but i have tried every thing for days and still the ExceptionInInitializerError puzzles me.

Comment: Need a stacktrace, what version of jetty, and what version of cometd.

Comment: jetty 9 and cometd 2.5.1

Answer (score 2):

The jetty-client api changed dramatically between jetty-8 and jetty-9 so if you are using cometd-2 with jetty-9 client apis then that is likely your problem.  Cometd-3 will support the new jetty-9 jetty-client api's.  I suspect you should be able to use jetty-8 jetty-client dependencies in your webapp and deploy onto jetty-9 as the container if you like.  You will just need to take care not to expose the jetty-client classes to the webapp classloader as you would have the jetty-8 ones already in the webapp.  I'll note this is one of the purposes of webapp classloader isolation, so you can have different versions of things in your webapp and your servlet container.  In this case, jetty-client would be like having two different versions of slf4j, you wouldn't want your container forcing you to use a particular version oh a dependency.  The cometd project will push out a RC for 3.0 fairly soon I would think, or you can use a SNAPSHOT of it if you want to work on the bleeding edge of cometd.  I would probably recommend just making use of the jetty-8 jetty-client and cometd 2.5 (or the latest release of it at least).

Comment: Mr. jesse mcconnell, i had tried your advice but i'm still having the same problem, any thing else you think i should try? i'm still investigating to solve this. thanks.